How do I create unique ID in div?
I have an infinite scroll page in Wordpress. While scrolling, the script loads, but it renders all the text1.js in to the first <article><div>.
This means that when I see article 1, text1.js loads correctly. I scroll to article 2, text1.js loads (correctly) again, but renders it back to article 1, so visually I see the contents of text1.js rendered twice in article 1.
The same effect happens again when scrolling to article 2, 3 etc. All text1.js' loads (while scrolling) and then renders it back to article 1.


document.getElementById("here1").appendChild(document.createElement('div')).textContent = 'Hello!';
<article>
  <div id="here1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="text1.js"></script>
  </div>
</article>



How do I create a script that creates a div with unique ID in the <div> while loading in text1.js ?
I tried multiple scripts, but because I'm a designer, I can't make heads or tails when it comes to Javascript.

Quick answer: Don't. Generating id attributes to stuff in to the DOM at runtime is very far from a good solution. Use the same class on all the elements instead and dynamically target them

Also, note that putting script elements in the middle of the DOM is not good practice. Put them in the <head> or just before </body>

if you need incrementing IDs then rather use the data attribute.

Is this script really supposed to just append the same, static text to each element? If so, it could certainly be done without using  IDs at all. If it needs any parameters however, to load content that is specific to the current element it is appending stuff to, that might be a different issue.

@tacoshy sorry, i don't understand 'data' attribute, what would I need to change to create unique IDs?

@RoryMcCrossan Thank you, i don't entirely understand, how would I dynamically target them then?

@CBroe in the future each text1.js would have different text. Only text. So I assume I would need to create unique IDs for them to be appropriately rendered in each article.

Rather than target a specific ID, you would use this.   So document.getElementById("here1").appendChild becomes this.appendChild.  However, that won't work with the code you have provided as this has no context.  In your actual code where you scroll and determine which "article" to load should also determine which node to add to.  Where you would be using a dynamic ID, use this.

@fdomn-m ah yes, I tried that before, but then all the text1.js would render at the very bottom of the page.

Even with different scripts, this could be done without using IDs. document.currentScript gives you access to the script element that the currently executing code originated from. So you can replace document.getElementById("here1") with document.currentScript.parentNode, to access the div that's wrapping the current script element, without any IDs, classes or other explicit identifiers/selectors.

@Cbroe I made the changes as you explained:
'document.currentScript.parentNode.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
.textContent = 'Hello!';'
Content = Hello! Loads properly in the first article, but when I scroll to the second, third, etc nothing loads. When I check the source code for the other articles i scrolled past I do see:  '' but no Content = Hello!

That might be an issue with how your infinite scroll script loads & inserts this content. If it f.e. uses assignment to innerHTML to append the new content, then any script elements contained in that new content would not be executed to begin with.

hm.. the weird this is, if I replace <script type="text/javascript" src="text1.js"></script> with a random ad script, it works perfectly with infinite scroll as intended.

It's hard to tell what exactly is going on, with just the info we have so far.

@CBroe thank you for your help, in the end it was indeed the infinite scroll script from the WP theme that was doing something/conflicting. I changed to a different infinite scroll theme, and now everything works as intended! back to the drawing board for me.
